# Thread.Sleep causes exception in JMeter when using socket.io-java-client library in AbstractJavaSamplerClient custom code

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jmeter

I implemented a custom AbstractJavaSamplerClient for JMeter, and the core runTest is like:

```
SampleResult results = new SampleResult();
results.sampleStart();
client.request("connector.ninjaHandler.savemove", opMsg, this);

while(optcode == null){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

results.sampleEnd();
results.setSuccessful(optcode);
```

However, I found `Thread.sleep()` will cause such exception:

> Uncaught Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.. See log file for details.

I googled around and people say thread.sleep will cause the timer failed. However, I cannot avoid it since I'm testing a web-socket server, which means I need to wait the server response back...(It runs OK if I delete the thread.sleep between sample start/end)

However, the sample test `org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.SleepTest` works well, which use the thread.sleep.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mandatory link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: You should accept your own answer so that it's helpful to others

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE thanks for reminding~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite ridiculous since I found the problem comes from the library that I use...
After fix the patch from [here](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/44), it works!